# Root div padding React (Styled Components)

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a simple React App, using Redux's `Provider` to wrap my `App` component.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import store from './store';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const MainContainer = styled.div`
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
`;

ReactDOM.render(
  <MainContainer>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </MainContainer>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);

registerServiceWorker();
```

However, when this app renders, there's a white gap around the edge (all sides) of the screen. What's the correct way to override the body tag so that the `App` content goes to the edge of the screen?

[image: White Margin should not be there.]

Comment: I think you are hitting the default styling of the browser. Try to add `body {margin:0;padding:0;}` to your CSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the default styling of your browser. You could use something like [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), or simply remove the margin and padding of the body yourself.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

You can do this with `injectGlobal`.

```
import { injectGlobal } from 'styled-components';

injectGlobal`
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answers, but I was looking for a Styled Components specific answer.

Turns out that Styled Components has a helper method, [`injectGlobal`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#injectglobal), which can override the global body tag.

Using this, one can set the desired properties – in this case, no margin / padding. So, adding the following to `index.js` solves the issue.

```
import { injectGlobal } from 'styled-components';

injectGlobal`
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

For `styled components v4` and onwards use `createGlobalStyle` instead:

```js
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components"

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    color: red;
  }
`

// later in your app's render method
<React.Fragment>
  <Navigation />
  <OtherImportantTopLevelComponentStuff />
  <GlobalStyle />
</React.Fragment>
```

[Styled Components FAQs](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#what-do-i-need-to-do-to-migrate-to-v4)

Answer (score 0):

In your "App.css" write this :

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

That's working for my home page.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function App() {
      document.body.style.padding = "0"; // these did the trick
      document.body.style.margin = "0"; // these did the trick

// using App2 because of async not allowed at root level
    
      return <App2></App2>;
    }
```